# Python + SQLite: Bind list of tuples

Tags: python, sqlite, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have an insert statement with only one parameter

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO sample (descr) VALUES (?);
```

And I have a list of tuples

```
[(a,b), (c,d)]
```

Now I am using

```
cur.executemany(query, listOfTuples)
```

Python doesn't like to receive 2 params, and demands only 1.
**What is the best way to bind all first values from the tuples with this statement?**

I've tried something like

```
cur.executemany(query, listOfTuples[0])
```

But now Python thinks I am giving it 4 params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to select just the first value; using a slice to create new tuples of length 1:

```
cur.executemany(query, [t[:1] for t in listOfTuples])
```

Quick demo to show the result of the list comprehension:

```
>>> listOfTuples = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> [t[:1] for t in listOfTuples]
[('a',), ('c',)]
```

You can also use a generator expression, which creates the tuple slices on the fly:

```
cur.executemany(query, (t[:1] for t in listOfTuples))
```

It could be that not all database APIs support an iterable and instead expect to be handed something that has a length though.

Comment: Just simple like that... Does this creates a new variable in memory? Or is this a memory reference on listOfTuples.

Comment: @Terence: it creates a new list and new tuples. You could use a generator expression too, *probably*.